# rails apartment gem copy data from one tenant to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, multi-tenant, data-migration, apartment-gem

I am creating a multi-tenant rails app for technical training centers. I'm using the [apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) gem so it creates different databases for each tuition center which has trainers and students. Students have their complete progress assessment data with analytics stored in the database tables.

Now i've come across a request from one of the students who want to move all their training record to a different trainer in a different organization.

How can i write a cloning function that takes all student records from a tenants database and copies it to another one using the apartment gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create rake task for it. In the rake task you need to switch between tenants and retrieve and restore data. Switch between schema using

```
      Apartment::Tenant.switch("your domain tenant name")
```

Comment: Within a rake task if we switch tenants the retrieved data don't have association data and won't work correctly.