# Rails/Multitenancy - How to transfer data from one account to another when using Apartment gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

I am using the Apartment gem for multitenancy and this separates the database for each tenant. Now I have a request to make a function to copy objects from one tenant to another. I've come [across this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341399/rails-apartment-gem-copy-data-from-one-tenant-to-another) but I think this would create a performance issue, as there are lots of relationships to be copied as well (I have Courses, which have many Lessons, which have many Attachments and so on). Is there a better way to copy those objects and their relationship without switching back and forth from a tenant?